# Converter Dias e Tempo (Horas x Minutos x Segundos) para somente Tempo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Possuo um Dataframe no qual estou realizando a diferença entre duas datas distintas para obter a diferença em Horas e Minutos, por exemplo:

```
 data_inicial = '2018-07-03 16:03:00'
 data_final   = '2018-07-05 00:00:00'
 duracao      = data_final - data_inicial
```

O resultado que estou buscando é : **'31:57:00'**,  ou seja o total de tempo da diferença entre as duas datas. Porém o resultado que tenho é : **'1 day, 7:57:00'**(A cada 24 horas ele escreve como 1 dia).

Tentei converter para um formato de HorasXMinutos com a instrução:

```
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(duracao, "%H:%M:%S"))
```

Porém recebi o erro:

> ValueError: time data '1 day, 7:57:00' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Não entendi a dúvida Maniero.. Dei os exemplos, o resultado que obtive, o código que utilizei e oque eu esperava receber como resposta ou seja fui totalmente especifico no que buscava. Por que a pendencia?

Comment: Essa pergunta está bem clara - peço que seja reaberta - a única coisa faltando é um tag "pandas" - o que clareia bastante , já que quem olhar sabe quais funções de adição e diferença de dados estão sendo usadas.  Eu e outras pessoas familiares sabemos do "pandas" por conta da palavra "dataframe" no corpo da questão - mas sem essa dica direto nas tags fica estanha mesmo - já que os exemplos mostrados não acontecem no Python "puro".

Comment: Muito obrigado pela observação jsbueno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que o %H do `datetime.strftime` vai apenas até 23. Conforme a documentação:

> %H - Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.

O que você tem que fazer é uma função que formata dessa forma pra você. Por exemplo:

```
def formatehours(interval):
    seconds  = interval.total_seconds()

    # formata minutos e segundos
    duration  = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds)
    formatted = duration.strftime('%M:%S')

    # formata horas e concatena com os minutos e segundos formatados
    return '%02d:%s' % (seconds / (60 * 60), formatted)
```

Ae para usar basta passar um timedelta pra essa função:

```
data_inicial = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-07-03 16:03:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
data_final   = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-07-05 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
duracao      = data_final - data_inicial

formatehours(duracao)
> '31:57:00'
```

Comment: Excelente begnini funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado! Realmente não havia me atentado a essa questão do %H, boa observação